# Synchronisation of two async calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

Good morning,

I have two async calls when my applications starts :
One that gets the device token for push notifications, and one that tries to log the user to Facebook.

I must not continue the application process if I don't have the results of the two async calls.

Currently, I'm doing something like this : two booleans `didFBConnect` and `didDeviceTokenObtained`.

I'm running in a thread this (apparently awful) :

```
while(!(didFBConnect && didDeviceTokenObtained)){ 
}
myFunctionToContinue();
```

Do you know what is the correct way to handle this kind of situation?

BR

Comment: Bad news, APNS registration failure callbacks are not always called.

Comment: Yeah, that's another problem in my backlog :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call the same function when your login and token calls finished and check the condition once, dont do this in a while-loop:

```
- (void)faceBookSuccess {
    ...
    didFBConnect = YES;
    [self tryToContinue];
}                      

- (void)tokenSuccess {
    ...
    didDeviceTokenObtained = YES;
    [self tryToContinue];
}                 

- (void)tryToContinue {
    if(didFBConnect && didDeviceTokenObtained) {
        myFunctionToContinue();
    }
}
```

Comment: How clever and simple... Thank you for your input!

Comment: The only thing to be careful of with this approach is that `myFunctionToContiue` may not be called on the main thread, which will cause you issues if you update any UI elements - I would suggest `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ myFunctionToContinue();
}); `

Comment: There is also a risk that `myFunctionToContinue` will get called twice @viggio24's solution is safer

Comment: yes if the two callbacks are not on the mainthread it might be called twice. You could switch to the mainthread before caling `tryToContinu` te be sure.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution to this is to create a GCD dispatch group. Looking at this example below (simple app), on the same method, that you will async call not in the main thread, you will:
1. get a global queue 
2. create a dispatch group
3. dispatch async in the global queue and in the group the two jobs (FB connect and Push notification token)
4. add a dispatch group wait for the jobs in the group to complete
5. after the wait add your myFunctionToContinue()

So what you do is to enqueue the two jobs but group them and then wait for the to finish. This is much more efficient than having the thread in loop while waiting for the two jobs to complete.

The reason why "gcdGroup" is not called in the main thread but in a dedicated serial queue is to avoid blocking the main thread while the group is waiting.

In general using GCD groups is quite convenient if your concurrent jobs are highly asynchronous and offers great flexibility as you can add other conditions without impacting in the code (simply create the block and put in the group). Besides you can dispatch also blocks that create their own groups so creating complex group graphs.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    dispatch_queue_t serial_queue = dispatch_queue_create("serial", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(serial_queue, ^{
        [self gcdGroup];
    });

    NSLog(@"Main thread not blocked...");

    return YES;
}

- (void)gcdGroup {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Start First job");
        sleep(5);
        NSLog(@"End First job");
    });

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Start second job");
        sleep(arc4random()%5);
        NSLog(@"End second job");
    });

    NSLog(@"Now waiting for group to finish...");

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"End of group");

}
```

Comment: yep, that is much proper solution than the accepted one in my view.

Comment: The problem is that I don't do the calls by myself, I only get the results thanks to the delegate

Comment: Yes, when you have delegate callbacks from async requests this solution is not suitable (or it cannot be easily implemented). If you still want to use a gcd solution, you can use gcd semaphores instead of group: still submitting your "gcdGroup" method to a serial queue (to avoid blocking the main thread with the semaphores) you can call your async methods (that is register for push and FB connect) and then signal the semaphores (each semaphore for method) on the delegate method, and putting the two semaphore wait signals just before the "callMyFunction()" call.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NSCondition:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html

instead of setting two boolean variables you should `signal` two conditions, and have the main thread/continuation thread `wait` for both of them (no matter in which order).

I suggest against using normal variables for synchronization, because without making assumptions over the CPU and the compiler you are not guaranteed that the variables are assigned in the order you expect. If you do maybe you will be lucky and it won't work, otherwise you will spend a lot of your time debugging race conditions and you will deserve it.